# What happen to the list variable in shell script

Tags: shell, ksh

```
#!/bin/ksh
list="one two three"
for var in $list ; do
    echo $var
    # Note: Changing this does NOT affect the loop items
    list="nolist"
done
```

I know the variable $list is read only once before the program starts so if i  change it inside loop it won't affect for loop running but what actually happening at memory level. How $list is created and destroyed or how actually ksh handles it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list` is just a string.  Interpolating it without quotes causes the shell to perform token splitting and wildcard interpolation; so the string is turned into a list of tokens, which the `for` loop loops over, binding the loop variable to each in turn.

This is not specific to `ksh`; this basic functionality goes all the way back to the original Bourne shell.

Programmers from other backgrounds often have a problem with the very lexical nature of Bourne shell syntax.  But it's really very simple; there are tokens, and the shell doesn't assign much more syntactical meaning to most tokens.  This means its behavior can be very dynamic -- a variable can be a command, or an option string, or a file name, or just about anything, and sometimes many of these things at once.

In specific terms of memory contents, the value of `$list` is copied token by token when the `for` line is parsed, so changing the value of the variable inside the loop is simple and undramatic.

Comment: Thanks for sharing thoughts . i did already understood about splitting and other stuff how it is treated as list,  i wanted to know about how $list is handled in memory after new value is assigned inside to it inside loop

Comment: @pkm: it's more a question of a copy of `$list` is split up before the first iteration of the loop, and the words thus generated are iterated over, regardless of what you do the variable(s) that originated them in the body of the loop.